# How to bind two different samples one on my pad and the other onto keyboard keys

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live

1. Have Oxygen v4 49
2. Using Ableton Lite x64
3. I have sample packs
4. Using Win 8.1 x64
5. Using Pod X3 Live as a soundcard.

I drag'n drop sample into my pad section, works fine.
I would like to drag'n drop another sample which works for keyboard keys.

My purpose is using different samples on my pad and keyboard keys same time, real-timed.
Then I want to start recording by using both pad section and keyboard keys which has binded different samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @eyam 's help, i found out a solution for this, and i think this is available just for m-audio **oxygen v4** series.

1. Create a midi channel and add just 1 instrument on it,
2. Create another midi channel and add drums on it,
3. For your first channel's instrument, in **MIDI From** seciton, change **All channels to Ch. 1**
4. For your second channel's drums, in **MIDI From** seciton, change **All channels to Ch. 10**

Works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use your keyboard keys to play one sample at different pitches, right?

For that purpose, you might want to use Live's **"Simpler"** instrument, instead of the "Drum Rack" you're probably using with your pad section. All you need to do is create a new MIDI track with a Simpler, and drag'n drop your sample onto it.

Then if you arm both tracks (Drum Rack and Simpler), you should be able to control both at the same time with your keys and your pad (I guess it's possible to route your MIDI controls so that your keys don't trigger your Drum Rack's samples and vice-versa)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I added a simpler instrument, but cannot drag'n drop nor my voice sample, neither drum rack. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @blankBird_ In the Simpler instrument there's a blank square zone with a "Drop Sample Here" inscription. This is where you should be droping your voice sample (mp3/wav/... file). Here's some video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pPGtxYJGOA

Comment: it works for now. But i want to improve. My 8 button pads starts from C0. How can i bind my 8 button pads starts from C -2 ?

Comment: @blankBird_ I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to do here, but your pad is bound to your Drum Rack right? The "notes" you trigger with your Pad for your Drum Rack are just a way for Live to indentify which slot to trigger (i.e. which sample to play). And you can place each sample of your Drum Rack on any slot you want by drag'n droping your sample on a slot. This is the way you can custom how your samples and pad buttons are bound to each other.

Comment: yes it works that way i did that, one sample for each pad button. But it conflicts with keyboard buttons. So when i both add drums and my synth sample, and press on C0 Key on midi keyboard, i hear both drum kick and synth sample C0 note. I'll update the post with images so i will be able to explain better. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: @blankBird_ I found this link : http://www.akaipro.com/kb/article/1509 
I know it's not the MIDI controler you're using but the solution might be analogue